# How to fix credit card input spacing

Tags: javascript

I researched this on stack overflow, tried different answers but nothing worked for me. Can someone fix the problem please.

```js
function spacingFunction() {
  let varNumber = document.getElementById('cardnumber');

  position = varNumber.selectionEnd;
  varNumber.value = varNumber.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim()
  varNumber.selectionEnd = position += ((varNumber.value.charAt(position - 1) === ' ' && varNumber.value.charAt(length - 1) === ' ' && length !== varNumber.value.length) ? 1 : 0);

}
```

```html
<input id="cardnumber" placeholder="e.g. 1234 5678 9123 0000" maxlength="19" type="text" onkeydown="spacingFunction()">
```

I tried all fix examples from the site. Need solution

Comment: Please try to rewrite the question and specify your problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ŠimonSlabý Hello, so i need 16 numbers credit card input with automatic space after every 4 numbers input. This solution is okay until you want to edit it in the middle. There comes problem with backspace and inserting number

Answer (score 1):

Your question was very unclear, but I believe that you asked to fix the spacing issue, here's a very good example [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/217u7fru/506/)

```js
input_credit_card = function(input)
{
    var format_and_pos = function(char, backspace)
    {
        var start = 0;
        var end = 0;
        var pos = 0;
        var separator = " ";
        var value = input.value;

        if (char !== false)
        {
            start = input.selectionStart;
            end = input.selectionEnd;

            if (backspace && start > 0) // handle backspace onkeydown
            {
                start--;

                if (value[start] == separator)
                { start--; }
            }
            // To be able to replace the selection if there is one
            value = value.substring(0, start) + char + value.substring(end);

            pos = start + char.length; // caret position
        }

        var d = 0; // digit count
        var dd = 0; // total
        var gi = 0; // group index
        var newV = "";
        var groups = /^\D*3[47]/.test(value) ? // check for American Express
        [4, 6, 5] : [4, 4, 4, 4];

        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        {
            if (/\D/.test(value[i]))
            {
                if (start > i)
                { pos--; }
            }
            else
            {
                if (d === groups[gi])
                {
                    newV += separator;
                    d = 0;
                    gi++;

                    if (start >= i)
                    { pos++; }
                }
                newV += value[i];
                d++;
                dd++;
            }
            if (d === groups[gi] && groups.length === gi + 1) // max length
            { break; }
        }
        input.value = newV;

        if (char !== false)
        { input.setSelectionRange(pos, pos); }
    };

    input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e)
    {
        var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;

        // Check for tab and arrow keys (needed in Firefox)
        if (code !== 9 && (code < 37 || code > 40) &&
        // and CTRL+C / CTRL+V
        !(e.ctrlKey && (code === 99 || code === 118)))
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var char = String.fromCharCode(code);

            // if the character is non-digit
            // OR
            // if the value already contains 15/16 digits and there is no selection
            // -> return false (the character is not inserted)

            if (/\D/.test(char) || (this.selectionStart === this.selectionEnd &&
            this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').length >=
            (/^\D*3[47]/.test(this.value) ? 15 : 16))) // 15 digits if Amex
            {
                return false;
            }
            format_and_pos(char);
        }
    });
    
    // backspace doesn't fire the keypress event
    input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) // backspace or delete
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            format_and_pos('', this.selectionStart === this.selectionEnd);
        }
    });
    
    input.addEventListener('paste', function()
    {
        // A timeout is needed to get the new value pasted
        setTimeout(function(){ format_and_pos(''); }, 50);
    });
    
    input.addEventListener('blur', function()
    {
        // reformat onblur just in case (optional)
        format_and_pos(this, false);
    });
};

input_credit_card(document.getElementById('cardnumber'));
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="cardnumber" placeholder="e.g. 1234 5678 9123 0000" maxlength="19" type="text" onkeydown="spacingFunction()">

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry i was in a rush. Looked up for edit button but didnt find. I need 16 numbers credit card input with automatic space after every 4 numbers input. The solution i have is okay until you want to edit input in the middle. There comes problem with backspace and inserting numbe. I will try your solution